# iOS TableView Referencing outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uistoryboard

I can not connect referencing outlet to showTableView on storyboard. I can only connect to view .I was trying to show the tableview with some data. Here are the codes that I am using.Please help me.Thank you.

```
ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *showTableView;


ViewController.m
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.


return [jsonResults count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
NSString *simpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:simpleIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

NSDictionary *appsdict = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *nameString = [appsdict objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.textLabel.text = [appsdict objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've set your `UIViewController`'s Custom Class to `ViewController` in the interface so you can properly link its outlets (including `showTableView`) to `ViewController`.

[image]

Comment: @user5 Great, can you click the checkmark next to my answer then to mark it as correct please?